# Mandatory Row of cells in an Excel Table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a row in my Excel table mandatory before users close the document, then display a pop-up message stating "cells require input".
I am running into an issue where users are still getting the pop-up message even if they have filled out all the mandatory cells.

[This is a screenshot of what all I typed out. I have this in the workbook area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r66FY.png)
I am typing what's in the screenshot, in the workbook area, and have it to run beforeclose.

This is the what I used below. My required fields is the row A3-O3

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Cells(3, 1)(3, 2)(3, 3)(3, 4)(3, 5)(3, 6)(3, 7)(3, 8)(3, 9)(3, 10)(3, 11)(3, 12)(3, 13)(3, 14)(3, 15).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Cell(s) require input", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

[view of my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnOig.png)

A plus would be a pop-up message letting the user know which cells are empty & for it to highlight the cells that are empty also

Answer (score 1):

Use [`WorksheetFunction.CountBlank`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countblank):

```
If Worksheetfunction.CountBlank(ActiveSheet.Range("A3:O3")) > 0 Then
   MsgBox "Cell(s) require input", vbInformation
End If
```

Or [`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells):

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:O3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "Cell(s) " & rng.Address(False, False) & " require input", vbInformation
End If
```

Note that `Cells(3, 1)(3, 2)(3, 3)(3, 4)(3, 5)(3, 6)(3, 7)(3, 8)(3, 9)(3, 10)(3, 11)(3, 12)(3, 13)(3, 14)(3, 15)` does not refer to `A3:O3`.

In the Immediate Window, put:

```
? Cells(3, 1)(3, 2)(3, 3)(3, 4)(3, 5)(3, 6)(3, 7)(3, 8)(3, 9)(3, 10)(3, 11)(3, 12)(3, 13)(3, 14)(3, 15).Address
```

The result is

```
$DB$31
```

Comment: I tried pasting that in there instead of my original. I didn't type anything in the original area & nothing happened; it let me close the document & it didn't throw a pop-up message.
I should preface I'm pretty new to doing more intermediate stuff in excel like this.

Comment: Did you include the `Cancel = True`? Also, you probably should specify a specific sheet and not use `ActiveSheet` (either implicitly or explicitly).

Comment: Ok I corrected those things. This is what I have in there now.

On Error Resume Next
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A3:O3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "Cell(s) " & rng.Address(False, False) & " require input", vbInformation
End If
Cancel = True
End Sub

After testing it shows this message "Cell(s) C3,E3:G3,J3:M3 require input". I left all mandatory cells blank then corrected it. Then closed completely out of the document & made sure all mandatory cells are filled. I get this regardless when I try close it.